# Bing Map REST API does not return distance in China

Tags: excel, api, rest, bing-maps

When I estimate the driving distance between two coordinates, of which at least one is located in China using the BING MAP REST API, the API returns negative distance.

When I estimate the driving distance in other countries, or from BING MAPS website there is no problem.

This is the code snippet I am using:

```
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins={Coordinate 1}&destinations={Coordinate 2}&travelMode=driving&o=xml&key={my-bing-key}
```

where coordinate is any of the values in parenthesis for: Beijng: (39.90208, 116.718521); Suzhou: (31.2983, 120.5832); Rome: (41.8902, 12.4922);

Would you have any suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the distance matrix service say that China, Japan, and Korea are not supported/covered.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What is the distance matrix?

Comment: It's a service that will calculate route distances between a set of origins and destinations. Kind of like a 2D grid of travel distances. You can get around the lack of support for China by simply using the routing service and making a call to for each origin-destination pair.